# C++ Initialize a non-static array of pointers in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

I want to initialize an array of pointers the nice way.. Something like

```
handler[numberOfIndexes] = {&bla, &ble, &bli, &blo , &blu};
```

But it doens't work this way. I get an error, obviously, because I'm trying to place an array of pointers to functions, in a single pointer to function:

```
cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘void (A::*)()’ in assignment
```

So, here's the code for you to test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    private:

    void first();
    void second();
    void third ();
    // and so on

    void(A::*handlers[4])(void);


    public:

    A();
};

void A::first()
{

}

void A::second()
{

}

void A::third()
{

}

A::A()
{
    //this is ugly
    handlers[0] = &A::first; 
    handlers[1] = &A::second;
    handlers[2] = &A::third;

    //this would be nice
    handlers[4] = {&A::first,&A::second,&A::third,0};//in static this would work, because it would be like redeclaration, with the type speficier behind
}

int main()
{
    A sup;
    return 0;
}
```

---

UPDATE:
In Qt this doesn't work.
I get :

```
syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
```

And if I change to

```
A::A() : handlers ({&A::first, &A::second, &A::third, 0})//notice the parentheses
```

then a this happens

```
Syntax Error: missing ')' before '{'
Warning: The elements of the array "A :: Handlers" are by default "initialized.
```

So, what's the problem with Qt?

---

By this point, you should have understood what I want to do. Just do a nice initialization of the array of pointers.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know about [member initialization lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)?

Comment: handlers[4] is undefined behavior because handler only has 4 elements.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yeah, I knew. Just didn't remember. But, I didn't knew it was different than assignment inside the constructor, so thank you anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use an actual initialization, not an assignment (arrays cannot be assigned to).

```
A::A() : handlers {&A::first, &A::second, &A::third, 0} {}
```

Comment: Good point, forgot about that.
But now I "know" that initialization is different than assignment, regarding these constructors' classes in C++

Comment: @WerBn I think that is another question. But GCC warns you against the parentheses if you put them in.

Comment: Yah, sorry, total mess. I'll update the warnings and errors in both cases